# Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation process through virt-manager

Tags: rhel, virt-manager

I'm going through the installation process using virt-manager which I will install a virtual Red Hat machines with on my physical host.
I have the image iso on the host and mounted it on `/media/cdrom`.
Red Hat lists four installation methods.

- Local CD/DVD
- Hard drive
- NFS directory
- URL

My first option is to use CD/DVD, although I end up getting a "disc was not found in any of your CDROM drives."
For hard drive it lists `sda` and `sr0`. We also have a NFS directory, which I can try if I don't get it going with the first two options.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit the VM settings adding a CDROM device (Add Hardware->Storage->IDE CDROM).

If you have already added it, you have to add the directory where you have stored the .iso file clicking on your local hypervisor (usually localhost QEMU), then go to Storage, then add the dir.

Once done, you can go back to the VM settings, and use the .iso file to boot the VM. Be careful that, after the first boot, you should connect it again to the VM and/or change to boot order, if needed.